# How to avoid Kmean local optima when using sklearn Kmeans

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to use use scikit kmean in production deployment and would want to use the default setting for kmean.init = k-means++. The question I have is that what are the chances that kmeans will fall into a local optima when it initializes cluster centroids?.

Notes says that "‘k-means++’ : selects initial cluster centers for k-mean clustering in a smart way to speed up convergence. See section Notes in k_init for more details".

Is there a data on the probability of getting a local optima ?.
If so, should I iterate to get  the minimal cost function ?.

Answer (score -1):

Probability of getting trapped into local optima, majorly depends on the nature of your data. If its explicitly grouped, then initial cluster might not have much of an impact on the final clusters results. [May be of use for you](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation).

Inspite of above point, for high dimensional dataset, it is preferable to try 10 or more iterations with different initial clusters and choose the one with best performance (one of performance metric could be [silhouette-coefficient](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#silhouette-coefficient))

Comment: I did try to iterate 100 times to get the minimum distortion cost function and choose the best kmean cluster centroid ,but it seems kmeans with init=k-mean++ is well optimized as it returned the same value for the cost function.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the variations comes only when the dataset is skewed. If you want to know more about k-means++, look at section 2.2 of the paper http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf